# how to upload SAP hybris to Azure artifacts and use for build dependancy

Tags: azure-devops, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to Devops. I am trying to set up Azure devops pipeline for SAP hybris.
Could you please give any pointers on how to upload SAP hybris framework
to Azure artifact and use it for build time dependancy?

So far I have created windows build agent.
I am not clear on entire process to create the pipeline for SAP hybris.
Has anyone configured similar kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipeline that publishes the OOTB(out of the box platform) into Azure Artifacts as an **universal package** . Such a task should look similar to:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: Publish Hybris Platform Universal Packages
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: '/yourPathOnTheMachineThatRunsThe/AzureAgent/folderContainingTheFilesToPublish'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'feed'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'theFeedInWhichYouWantToPublish'
    packagePublishDescription: 'Hybris Platform'
```

After publishing you can use another(Universal Package) task to do the download and further use it in the build process.

The full documentation of Azure Universal Package task can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops)